# Multiple Instances of Geary, Files, etc. for different workspaces?

Tags: plank, desktop, pantheon-mail

I am just getting started with workspaces, and I can easily have two different instances of Chrome running in two different workspaces, but for other apps (Files, Geary, Keepass, etc.) when I click on it in the Plank of one workspace, it pops over to the other workspace to the open window.

This is annoying. Is there a way I can have multiple instances of apps open in different workspaces?

AND as a bonus, can I have multiple Planks too, so I can see what's open in each workspace? Now the Plank just shows all open windows across all workspaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry I can't provide a full answer right now, but I can answer one small part of it.

To open new instances of Files you can right click its icon in Plank and click "New Window". I opened two in separate workspaces and the behaviour changes to show or hide Files instead of switching. You can also right click the icon when multiple instances are open to switch to the other instance(s).

---

If anyone provides a full answer, feel free to take this info or edit yours into this answer.